# Android SQLite Concurrency (trying to reopen an already closed connection)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sqlite

This type of question has been asked a lot, but I could not find any answer that satisfies me.

**Question**
How should I maintain multiple open SQLite connections on multiple threads?
Is it possible to check how many connections are open and call close() only if none are?

**EDIT**
I accepted the answer below as SQLite is very fast and synchronizing ALL the sql API methods (only one will run at a time) may not be too hurting.
That being said, I'll still be happy to hear about a solution that synchronize read()s and write()s, so that multiple read() can be done at once...

**Background**
I'm building an Android app and in some places I use few Internet connections (GET requests).
When those requests finish, all their threads access to the SQLite, most for writing.
When the threads try to connect simultaneously, I get the error mentioned in title.

I KNOW why it happens:
The way I do it, each "SQLite API" method (API that I wrote) is starting by opening the connection and finishes by closing it. Write/read open() is used whenever needed.

So when one thread closes the connection (the API method finishes) and the other is still using a cursor or whatever, the error occurs and this exception is thrown.

Here is a code example to demonstrate:

```
public class MySQL{
    private SQLiteOpenHelper mHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
    private static MySQL myInstance;
    ...

    //singleton
    public synchronized static MySQL getInstance(Context context){
        if(myInstance == null){
            myInstance = new MySQL(context);
        }
        synchronized (myInstance) {
            return myInstance;
        }
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openRead() throws SQLException{
        return myDatabase = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    }


    public SQLiteDatabase openWrite() throws SQLException{ 
        return myDatabase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    //close helper
    public void close(){
        mHelper.close();
    }

    public static void createSomeEntry(){
         openWrite();
         myDatabase.query(...);
         ...
         close();
    }

    public static void getSomeEntry(){
         openRead();
         Cursor c = myDatabase.query(...);
         ...//use cursor in a loop
         close();
    }
}
```

So let's say any two-combination of these method run at the same time from different threads.

As you can see, I try to synchronize the use/hold of 'myInstance' with the hope that as long as one thread holds this variable, it's the only one that can use it.
It doesn't work apparently, and it will only slow down everything anyway, I prefer something better.

How do I fix this logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java driver for SQLite does not support true concurrent multithreaded access.  It's only "thread safe" in the sense that use from multiple threads should not corrupt the data.  I think the best you can do is to open a single connection, and then have each thread lock the connection while using it, giving the lock up when it's done.  I'm not familiar with Android programming specifically, but something like the following might work:

```
public class MySQL{
    private static MySQL myInstance;
    private SQLiteOpenHelper mHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
    ...

    //initialize
    public synchronized static void initialize(Context context){
        if(myInstance == null){
            myInstance = new MySQL(context);
        }
    }

    public synchronized static void createSomeEntry() {
        myInstance.myDatabase = myInstance.mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        myInstance.myDatabase.query(...);
        ...
        myInstance.mHelper.close();
    }

    public synchronized static void getSomeEntry() {
        myInstance.myDatabase = myInstance.mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = myInstance.myDatabase.query(...);
        ...//use cursor in a loop
        myInstance.mHelper.close();
    }
}
```

Note the replacement of getInstance() with an initialize function that doesn't return anything, and the elimination of all other public functions except createSomeEntry() and getSomeEntry().  Since all public methods are synchronized on the class, only one thread can use the database at a time, which should resolve the issue of SQLite not supporting concurrent access.

If you truly need concurrent access, I think your choices are either to figure out how to access the SQLite database from multiple processes rather than multiple threads, which was the approach that worked for my needs, or to switch to another database.  I suppose you could also make driver changes yourself to make the driver truly multithreaded.

Comment: Oh...I was afraid that will be the answer. I find it very odd that there isn't a "concurency API" for Android...

Can you show me an example for locking connection? What's wrong with my solution inside the getInstance() method? thanks!

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the Android specific libraries, but you might be able to start with making everything in your class private except for the createSomeEntry() and getSomeEntry() methods, which would be the only methods your other code would use.  Making the createSomeEntry() and getSomeEntry() methods synchronized would take care of contention by client threads.  You might need some additional adjustments inside the class, but that would be a start.

Comment: That is already the case...The only way to even use these functions is calling getInstance(). The problem is that even when synchronizing these methods, it doesn't mean two separate methods can't access the db at the same time. There must be a solution using something like my getInstance() method, with synchronizing the instance...

Comment: I'm saying to make the getInstance() method private as well.  Client code would not call getInstance() directly.  You would only call it from within your MySQL class.

Comment: Interesting...and how would I change my code so it will actually synchronize instances? I mean, this alone will not solve the problem.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "synchronize instances"?  The internal changes I see that would be needed would be to make the myInstance variable volatile, and call getInstance() at the beginning of createSomeEntry() and getSomeEntry().  Making createSomeEntry() and getSomeEntry() synchronized will ensure only one thread can execute one of these functions at a time.

Comment: I completely understand your logic and it sounds great, but I can't understand how would it work.. If I declare the instance as volatile, would it mean that no more than one thread can hold it? As I see it, if one thread finishes the method getInstance(), another one can call it as well. But then again, one would call openWrite() after the other one did and it will crush.

Comment: To make myself clear, what I need is this very known technique: only one thread can be inside "write" operation, many can be inside "read", and thats it. Usually you would define various lock variables, but that's Java, there must be a simpler solution. So if one thread called openWrite() and hasn't called close(), I want to lock all other threads.

Comment: In my experience, the SQLite Java driver does not even support concurrent multithreaded reads; my issues with SQLite concurrency came up in a case where I was only using the database on a read only basis, with no writes.  I've edited my answer to show some example code that would ensure that only one thread accesses the database at a time, even for reads, which I hope should make things clearer.

Comment: Incidentally, I suggested "volatile" to ensure the variable was visible to other threads; otherwise one thread could still see a null value even after another thread had set the variable.  My example code does not do that because all access to the variable is from within synchronized methods, which also ensures visibility across threads.  Visibility across threads is a different issue from locking, but is something that also has to be handled in multithreaded code.

Comment: Just to be sure, making the public methods static make the ENTIRE class to be synchronized? meaning that accessing one method is synchronized with ALL other static methods?

Comment: Yes.  Static synchronized methods all synchronize on the class, so only one such method can be running at a time, in any thread.

Comment: perfect! Now I just need to change thousands of code lines:) thanks, I'll post back when it's done and working